# Python- Read header at specific line

Tags: python, pandas, header, word-wrap

I'm trying to read in a text file that has multiple headers - but the header starts on line 1000.  For example, my headers look like this :

LN  Type  Pct  Amount  Principal
TP  Code       Due     Owed

So, as you can see, my headers are word wrapped and starts at line 1000 in the text file.  How can I import this into Python?  So that is recognizes my headers and columns?

My code so far:

```
topheader='Acct Total'
with open('1000.txt') as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f,1):
        if topheader in in line:
            df = pd.read_csv('1000.txt',header=[num,next()] #I knw this is incorrect, but I need help
```

Every time 'Acct Total' is in the file (at line 999) the header is on the next line (at line 1000).  How can I get Python to read in the header at line 1000, and also recognize that the header is word wrapped?

Comment: FYI - there are 4 columns with 4 headers that are word wrapped on two lines.  So for example, LN \n TP is one column.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('1000.txt', skip_rows=999, header=[0,1])`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like below might work for you.  StringIO just makes a string behave like a file.  That's just to make this code snippet runnable.

```
from io import StringIO  # just for example

text = """#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
LN Type Pct Amount Principal
TP Code Due Owed
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 1 0"""

f = StringIO(text)

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("LN"):
        break  #find where the columns start
line2 = f.readline()  # get the next row
# construct column names
names = [f"{a}_{b}" for a,b in zip(line.split(), line2.split())]

# file is now at the start of the data, so pandas will start reading from there
# pass in the column names explicitly
# read_table and read_csv have similar call signatures
df=pd.read_table(f, header=None, sep=" ", names=names)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   LN_TP  Type_Code  Pct_Due  Amount_Owed
0      1          2        3            4
1      5          6        7            8
2      9          1        2            3
3      4          5        6            7
4      8          9        1            0
```

Comment: This is close - but when I run the file I keep getting the error:  ValueError: Duplicate names are not allowed.

Comment: Print out the names variable to see what name is duplicated.